# How to disable (Record Macro) menu (by macro codes)

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

In (Microsoft Excel) In (Tools > Macro) There is a menu with name of (Record Macro)

How to disable (Record Macro) menu by a macro code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this is possible, it probably has to be done via the Ribbon, so you will need to modify the file's Ribbon XML and add appropriate VBA callbacks to hijack and disable that command.

Comment: Why would you want to disable record macros? I do not see the reason for this?

Comment: well, david's right. SO is not intended to give you full solutions, but to help you with malfunctioning solutions you provided yourself. There are tools (like the "Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office") which let you  edit the xml structure (ribbons)

Comment: Downvote because you didn't show any attempt to solve the problem and when presented with an appropriate answer you demand, "please don't answer without enough knowledge!!!". tl:dr...Rude.

Comment: Downvote because being rude will not gain anything to you in this environment. @DavidZemens tried to give some feedback to guide you to your answer but instead of trying to look for it you just replied him in a rude way.

Comment: sorry, i was a little angry. excuse me. thank you all for your time and your help

Comment: you can also check [Ron de Bruin's](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm) site for similar applications. It may help. and also you can check [Office Talk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390805(office.11).aspx) to see how to manipulate ribbon

Comment: it seems new users are unable to Upvote comments anyway thank you for the info :)

Comment: You might record a macro to see it (sorry, bad joke lol)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ to stop tracing an excel project lock by hackers i need to disable it.

Comment: @mrbungle is it possible to stop recording a macro by a macro code which is compatible with all versions of excel? i think by this way we can stop unauthorized recordings every time we need to start a confidential code in our excel project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop like this:

```
Dim ctl As CommandBarControl

For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=184)
    ctl.Enabled = False
Next ctl
```

Comment: It won't work beyond 2003, I think. You can't disable command bars that way anymore.

Comment: It's not intended to, since the OP mentioned the Tools - Macro commands. They don't exist past 2003. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure you even can in later versions due to the button on the status bar - though you could hide that.

Comment: it seems new users are unable to Upvote comments anyway thank you for the info :)

Comment: @DigiLadder new users **are** able to *accept* answers, though :)

Comment: @Rory yes I'm playing with it in Excel 2010 but the button on the status bar, for some reason, is not disabled. The list of Office Controls in Excel only shows two items with idMso=MacroRecord, in the View and Developer tab. I tried disabling the command but that's not doing anything.

Comment: @DavidZemens tnx i did :)

Comment: @DavidZemens The status bar isn't part of the ribbon model. That and the new sheet button  I don't think can be disabled.

Comment: gaaaah that's frustrating... why would MS provide a means to disable *commands*, but then allow commands to be added to a part of the UI over which we have no control!!

Comment: The new sheet button can technically be disabled by `DisplayWorkbookTabs = False` but then that hides **all** tabs, and you'd need to use hyperlinks or some other form controls to navigate.

Comment: Technically, that's hidden not disabled.  :)  As to why, I don't know. It's been mentioned to them but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: I added an answer using the ribbon model for newer versions of Excel. @mrbungle

Comment: is it possible to stop recording a running macro by a macro code which is compatible with all versions of excel? i think by this way we can stop unauthorized recordings every time we need to start a confidential code in our excel project...

Comment: Sounds like you need to just disable the developer tab

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2007+, you need to manipulate the ribbon. This is as good as I can come up with, the problem as Rory and I discussed in comments to his answer is that the `MacroRecord` command can be added to the Status Bar, and the Status Bar is not part of the ribbon model.  The hack is to disable the status bar, but since that is an *application*-level property, you need an event handler to re-enable it for other workbooks.

**Ribbon XML** to disable the controls:

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="ribbonOnLoad">
    <commands>
           <command idMso="MacroRecord" 
               enabled="false" 
           />
      </commands>
      <ribbon>
      <tabs>
      <tab>
      <group idMso="GroupMacros">
            <button idMso="MacroRecord" 
                enabled="false"
            />
      </group>
      <group idMso="GroupCode">
            <button idMso="MacroRecord"
                enabled="false"
            />
      </group>
      </tab>
      </tabs>
      </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**VBA in a standard module** to handle the ribbon callbacks and associated procedures:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
Public XLEvents As New cEventClass

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub ribbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Call SetEventHandler
    Call ToggleStatusBar(ThisWorkbook)
End Sub


Sub SetEventHandler()

If XLEvents.appevent Is Nothing Then
    Set XLEvents.appevent = Application
End If

End Sub

Sub ToggleStatusBar(wb As Workbook, Optional ret$)

    If (wb.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name) Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Status Bar Disabled"
    Else
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If

End Sub
```

**VBA in a Class module** called "cEventClass" to do application event-handling:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents appevent As Application
Dim ret As String
Private Sub appevent_WorkbookActivate(ByVal wb As Workbook)

    Call ToggleStatusBar(wb, ret)

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, I was going to try and mess with it but work pulled me away.  I'm go save this in my Evernote with all my other ribbon/vba edits I have for some Access apps we develope here.  I like having this stuff in my backpocket :)